# string slicing not accepting variables

Tags: python

I am writing a short method to slice a string based upon the index of comma's in a different method. I droped everything into one code for easy viewing.

```
with open(testconfig) as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
        initlist=[]
        string_slice_list=[]
        b=0
        for line in lines:
            if "ML_STARConfig" in line:
                b+=1
                liste=sfind(line,",")
                liste.insert(0,0)
                input("line is {}sfind list of characters is {} and there should be a zero in position 0".format(line,liste))
                liste=list(reversed(liste))
                slices=[]
                for i in range(1,len(liste)):#make a list of tuples that have the beginning and end indexes of a "useful slice" of the string "line"
                    slices.append((liste[i-1],liste[i]))
                for item in slices:
                    b=item[0]
                    e=item[1]
                    word=line[b:e]
                    input("line is {} word indexes are {},{} and this should be a word ={}".format(line,b,e,word))
```

the method accepts a single line from a file and creates a list of the indexes of the comma's in the line. I assign each pair of indexes to a tuple and append each tuple to a list. and then loop over the list of tuples to extract each of the words of interest from the line. Except when I pass the numbers from the list of tuples it will not slice the string. and returns nothing in the last line. Here is my stack trace or this code...

```
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
sfind list of characters is [0, 13, 21, 27, 29, 33, 52] and there should be a zero in position 0
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
  word indexes are 52,33 and this should be a word =
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
  word indexes are 33,29 and this should be a word =
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
  word indexes are 29,27 and this should be a word =
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
  word indexes are 27,21 and this should be a word =
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
  word indexes are 21,13 and this should be a word =
line is ML_STARConfig, Master, C0RF, , rf, 7.1S B 2011-10-05, Firmware version
  word indexes are 13,0 and this should be a word =
```

the Variable for the line clearly works and the variable for the beginning and end indexes are there but the line[#:#] command just magically stops working and its very frustrating. I have no Idea what is causing this. I have tried making a list of lists of comma indexes and it is still not working.

What on earth am I missing here?

Comment: This seems like just an over-complicated version of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: Trying that out now.

Comment: :DD We all have to learn. Nice example on how minutes of research could save hours of work

Comment: No worries.  For future reference, Python has one of the largest/best collections of supporting libraries.  I frequently ask myself "has anyone else tried to do this before?" - if the answer is "yes", chances are there is a python library that can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I reversed the order of the slice and that fixed it. Sorry I didnt realize I was trying to perform the slice in reverse, apparently this doesnt work.

to clarify, if you do

```
line[b:e]
```

and b>e it will give you a whole lot of nothing.

Comment: You can iterate backward you just need to pass a third argument that is the step size (sign in direction) ```print( line[b:e:-1]```